# Auth system laravel just with phone number and verification sms code

Tags: laravel, authentication

my web app is laravel and my users do not have email and password and they register and login with phone number and verification sms code.
My db is Mongodb.
How to I change Auth system laravel?

Comment: Are you verifying the phone number during login every time or just one time during registration?

Comment: I do not have register form if user submit login form for first time then laravel inserts user's phone number to db (Mongodb or MySql)

Answer (score 2):

you will need to implement your own Auth system .First you will need to send SMS  I recommend using Twilio https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-sms-portal-laravel-php-twilio

Here is some functions I made before

```
    public function sendVerificationCode(VerificationCodeRequest $request)
    {
            $twilioService = new TwilioService() ;
            $otp = random_int(1000, 9999);
            $result = $twilioService->sendVerificationCode(request('mobile'), $otp );
            if (!$result) {
                return response()->json(["message"=>__('messages.wrong_number')],422);
            }
        }
        $user = User::updateOrCreate(
            ['mobile' =>  request('mobile')],
            ['verification_code' => $otp]
        );
        return response()->json(["message"=>__('messages.otp_sent')],200);
    }



    public function login(MobileLoginRequest $request)
    {
        $user = User::where("mobile",request('mobile'))->firstOrFail();
        if($user->verification_code==$otp){
            if ( !$userToken=JWTAuth::fromUser($user)) {
                return response()->json(['message' => __('messages.Unauth')], 401);
            }
        }else{
            return response()->json(['message' => __('messages.invalid_otp')], 401);
        }
        $user->update(["verified"=>1,"login_type"=>"mobile"]);
        return $this->respondWithToken($userToken,$user);
    }
     protected function respondWithToken($userToken,$user)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $userToken,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => JWTAuth::factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'profile'    => $user,
        ], 200);
    }
```

the twilio service file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;


class TwilioService
{


    public function sendVerificationCode($number,$otp){
        return $this->sendMessage("your Verification Code is :  $otp ",$number);
    }


    public function sendNotification($recipient,$body,$title){
        return $this->sendMessage($body,$recipient,$title."\n");
    }



    private function sendMessage($message, $recipient,$title="")
    {
        try {
            $account_sid = getenv("TWILIO_SID");
            $auth_token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
            $twilio_number = getenv("TWILIO_NUMBER");
            $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
            $client->messages->create("$recipient",
                    ['from' => $twilio_number, 'body' => $title.$message] );
            return true;
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            Log::error("$th");
            Log::info("-------unable to send SMS to phone $recipient -------------");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks but you do not understand problem.
let me I explain more detail
1) user enters just his phone number on login form
 2)  laravel sends sms verificacion code to his mobile and show verificacion code form to user 
 3)  user must enters his verificacion code on verificacion code form
 4)  laravel checks  verificacion code 
 4-1) if user enters form for first time then laravel inserts user's phone number to db (Mongodb or MySql)   
5) laravel sends user to his profile
Users do not have any email and password for all the time

Comment: yes my friend . that is what I understood.

Comment: you need to build this auth logic yourself using a third party called twilio to send SMS.